# TabItem rotation WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new in WPF and i am trying to create animation on select and unselect tab item in tab control by using style.

Unfortunatly it does not work and i dont know why. What is wrong in this style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="MainTabControlItems">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />

                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                             To="30" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />

                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="-30" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>           
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<TabControl Name="tcAplabet"
                    SizeChanged="tcAplabet_SizeChanged" SelectionChanged="tcAplabet_SelectionChanged"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    TabStripPlacement="Left"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}">

            <TabItem Header="A"  IsSelected="True" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="B" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="C" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="D" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="E" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="F" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="G" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="H" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="CH" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="I" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="J" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="K" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="L" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="M" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="N" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="O" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="P" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="Q" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="R" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="S" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="T" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="U" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="V" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="W" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="X" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="Y" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />
            <TabItem Header="Z" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainTabControlItems}" />

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:MainTabContent Name="cMainTabContent" Margin="2"></controls:MainTabContent>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

        </TabControl>
```

Thanks for advice...

Comment: LayoutTransform and not RenderTransform . enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, but if i a change to <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.LayoutTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="30" Duration="0:0:5"/> it isnt work

Comment: I thought it was just unwanted results. i'm guessing your animation isn't triggered at all...

Comment: o'k i know the problem. RenderTransform is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem an instance of RenderTransform wasn't created for your TabItem.
It's applying an animation on a null object and swallowing any exception that occurs from that.

Add this to your style :

```
 <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
     <Setter.Value>
         <TransformGroup>
             <RotateTransform />
             <TranslateTransform />
             <SkewTransform />
             <ScaleTransform />                                
         </TransformGroup>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
```

*Also you might want to set RenderTransformOrigin to the center of your Tabtem as to not rotate on the Top,Left corner of it.(unless that's what you men't to do)